# How to show video from server in new Today widget in ios10 using swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, ios10-today-widget

I am trying to show video on today widgets using swift3 on ios10 devices. I tried using AVPlayer and  AVPlayerViewController but somehow the video is not loading. Same thing is working if its on normal viewcontroller inside the app.

Any  help would be highly appreciated..

thanks in advance